# Web Service Consuming .NET "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime” as There is an error in XML document (2, 742)

Tags: .net, web-services, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

We are try to consume a third party Web Service (peoplesoft). I tested the Request & response of required web Services in SoapUI, Its working fine but when I try the same Web services in .Net it gives the error :” String was not recognized as a valid DateTime”  as There is an error in XML document (2, 742).

It’s seems that some Datetime fields are received empty from server side and when the request try to parse in response it gives the error.

Response_Object = Web_Service_ref.Web_Service_Method(Request_Object);

Any suggestion plz.

Comment: What is the exact xml in the location where it fails?

Comment: @Marc Web service(WS) is running on another server for student registration.we send request for user registration using WS method. the WS CreateUser Method take Request Object as parameter and return a response object. In java and SoapUI its working fine but in .NET the method thrown a exception "There is an error in XML document (2, 742)." through fiddler its observer the empty date field/node create the exception.                                   Response_Object = Web_Service_ref.Web_Service_Method(Request_Object);

Comment: if the problem is an empty date field/node, then: don't send an empty date field/node... what is the value you are trying to send here?